# TypeError: each_blocks[i] is null in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a problem with creating and updating lists of components in Svelte.
I have a list of TodoItems, i.e:

*App.html*

```html
<!-- ... -->
<!-- The culprit -->
{#if todos.length}
  {#each todos as todo, i}
    <TodoItem
     on:remove='remove(i)'
     title={todo.title}
   />
  {/each}
{/if}
<script>
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.html';

export default {
 components: {
   TodoItem,
 },
 data() {
   return {
     todos: [{ title: 'Hello World' }],
   };
 },
 methods: {
   remove(key) {
     let { todos } = this.get();
     this.set({
       todos: todos.filter((_, i) => i !== key),
     });
   },
 },
};
</script>
```

*TodoItem.html*

```html
<li>
  <div class="view">
    <label>{title}</label>
    <button on:click='fire("remove")' class="destroy"></button>
  </div>
</li>
```

It errors `Cannot read property 'i' of null` (chrome) or `TypeError: each_blocks[i] is null` (firefox) when the list is updated.

Here is a [REPL example](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.7.1&gist=03509c8404f910a2329d1ba47547ed11).

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.7.1&gist=c2a907694e3914b502ed8cc2e7d8ae50 Can you create a repro? If you've found a bug, please raise an issue on https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues — thanks

Comment: @RichHarris I have updated the post with a better example and created a [REPL example](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.7.1&gist=03509c8404f910a2329d1ba47547ed11)

Comment: Thanks — have opened an issue https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1525

Comment: By the way, a workaround is to convert the list into a *keyed each block* — note the addition of `(todo.title)` (in a real app you'd probably want something more like `(todo.id)`):  https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.7.1&gist=195c70275a687de664f5b70d270cebda. Keyed each blocks are documented at https://svelte.technology/guide#keyed-each-blocks

Comment: Thanks – another workaround, albeit hacky, is to have an inverted if statement with an :else, i.e `{#if !todos.length} {''} {:else} <...list /> {/if}`